# Query Windows 10/8 Monitor Scaling from Python Script?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, scale, scaling

I have written an application in python 3.6 and would like to run a command to see what the current scaling for a monitor is in Windows 10 or 8 - something like how the following returns screen resolution:

```
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize_l = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
screensize_w = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

I understand that the easiest way to do this may be to make my application DPI aware, but doing so causes lots of additional problems in my application - so I would like to avoid this option.

I have looked in the windows documentation and thought "GetDpiForMonitor" or "GetScaleFactorForMonitor" may be what I am looking for, but don't know how to implement these commands.

I already use both win32api and ctypes so anything relying on either of these would be fine - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I solved my own problem by painstakingly making my program re scale all fixed elements based on the size of the screen returned by user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) and user32.GetSystemMetrics(1).  I just calculated an adjustment factor associated with my original atticipated screensize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 10, the following code (you need `pywin32`):

```py
import ctypes
import win32api

PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE = 2
MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI = 0

def print_dpi():
    shcore = ctypes.windll.shcore
    monitors = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()
    hresult = shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE)
    assert hresult == 0
    dpiX = ctypes.c_uint()
    dpiY = ctypes.c_uint()
    for i, monitor in enumerate(monitors):
        shcore.GetDpiForMonitor(
            monitor[0].handle,
            MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI,
            ctypes.byref(dpiX),
            ctypes.byref(dpiY)
        )
        print(
            f"Monitor {i} (hmonitor: {monitor[0]}) = dpiX: {dpiX.value}, dpiY: {dpiY.value}"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_dpi()
```

gives the following output on my machine with 3 monitors and 1 scaled to 125%:

```
Monitor 0 (hmonitor: <PyHANDLE:65539>) = dpiX: 96, dpiY: 96
Monitor 1 (hmonitor: <PyHANDLE:65537>) = dpiX: 120, dpiY: 120
Monitor 2 (hmonitor: <PyHANDLE:65541>) = dpiX: 96, dpiY: 96
```

If you do not want to set your own application as a dpi-aware per monitor, you could try launching some variant of the above code in another process using the `multiprocessing` module and retrieve the results.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the scaling factor using ctype and then modify your dimensions according to it.

```
import ctypes

scale_factor = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0)
```

If scale factor = 150%, this will return 150. 
*Its probably useful to divide by 100 when your working with this number in your app.*

Comment: From the documentation for [`GetScaleFactorForDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorfordevice): *"This function is not supported as of Windows 8.1. Use [`GetScaleFactorForMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor) instead."*

Comment: Thanks for that info. I just tested it and its still working for me (Windows 10). I use it in my code on multiple windows machines without issue. I think it can help other people out as well.