# Python tkinter- Conpensate Windows Display Scaling

Tags: python, tkinter, display, scaling

My program has a fixed resolution main window, i dont want it to be resizable, but some PCs with very small monitors will have high display scalling setting, so the program cannot show the full window, is there a way to extract this scaling factor so i can conpensate that? Or is there a way to compile the exe so that it does not scale according to the settings?

Comment: Why don't you want it to be resizable? Users should be able to control the size of their windows, unless you're making a kiosk-like application.

Comment: user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) and user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)  here is link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253948/query-windows-10-8-monitor-scaling-from-python-script

Answer (score 2):

You can get the scaling factor using ctype and then modify your dimensions according to it.

```
import ctypes

scale_factor = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0)
```

If scale factor = 150%, this will return 150. 
*Its probably useful to divide by 100 when your working with this number in your app.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the answer for your problem is below:

```
fixedWidth = 1920
fixedHeight = 1080

user_monitor = get_monitors()
scale = user_monitor.width / fixedWidth

if user_monitor.widht < fixedWidth:
    fixedWidth = user_monitor.width
if user_monitor.height < fixedHeight:
    fixedHeight = user_monitor.height
```

and of course you have to multiply by `scale` the rest of you program sizes to scale down your program

Comment: Thank u for replying! but it wasnt quite what i meant, my monitor is 3240*2160 and the windows scalling setting is 200, so if a open a window that is set to 500*500, it will actually appear as 1000*1000 on my diaplay, if the scaling setting is higher, the window will appear even bigger and some widgets are hidden, while the screen resolution is always 3240*2160! So, if it is possible to get this scaling setting and reduce size accordingly?